# Upload a file that lives on the website server to another service via ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, file-upload

I'm just wondering if what I propose is possible to do with any file, not just images.

Basically on the website server I have a assets directory with some generic files.  These files can apply to a different number of things, like 'x_button.png' for a close button but there are also config.json files that are in that directory as well.  I need the ability to push any one of these files to another server via AJAX.

Currently we use the file dialog and get a files array with the actual file and using formdata, push that up to the server.

For the images I could set an image tag to that local location then use the canvas to get the data uri and change that into a Blob but I am unsure if there is anything I can do for a .json file or even further any filetype.

I'm not looking for a written out solution, just if someone has encountered the need to do something like this before and the jist of the basic steps to solve the problem.  Thanks!

Comment: Set the values to a hidden input and post the form to a hidden iframe since Ajax can not talk to another domain without CORS.

Comment: They are on the same domain.  The problem is that I can't set the value of the hidden input since I can't chose that file since it lives on the webserver and not the local file system.

Comment: If the file is on your server, you can read it. It is a basic XMLHttpRequest to fetch it. I question why in the world you would not do it on your backend if that is the case.

Comment: Two different teams, and two completely independent systems unfortunately.  I agree with what you are saying about the backend and the current system is complex and we thought we could get through it this way.  Looks like it is turning out not to be the case.

Answer (score 1):

you can call a php code with ajax to upload file via ftp

check [ftp_exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-exec.php)

or you may send the file using