# Reading in a file then creating a Blob of that file

Tags: javascript, ajax, blob

If I want to read in a file (say: audio.mp3) and I know where it lives, and I want to recreate that file via javascript in a Blob so I can append it into FormData, is that possible?

```
            $.ajax({
                'type': 'GET',
                'url': sounds/audio.mp3
            }).done(function(body) {
                var blob = new Blob([body], {'type': 'audio/mpeg'});
                var formdata = new FormData();

                //Set other things then...
                data.append('audio.mp3', blob);
            }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
                alert('failed');
            });
```

It submits correctly to another web server that I need it to be sent to and I get a URL back to that file as re-created by the Blob, but I can no longer listen to the sound.  Is this possible or am I just grasping at air?

Is it possible I am just forgetting to put something in to make the data structure correct for audio?

Comment: Asking the same [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13923814/upload-a-file-that-lives-on-the-website-server-to-another-service-via-ajax#comment19196025_13923814) again?

Comment: That and 67% accept... You may well be grasping at air. I don't think this is the way to do this. You can make the ajax call a file on your side that uses curl to post to a remote site. That may be cleaner than trying to pass blob data... I'm basing this off of nothing though so don't take my word for it. I would have tried a back end communication first though.